Coinmarketcap API to Google Sheets / Google Scripts Get Live coin price
Hi I'm trying to get the price of specific Crypto coins to add to a google sheets. I've managed to get this google script working when I hard code the value of "symbol" however I'm trying to pass the coin I'm trying to price out and I think I'm running to a simple syntax issue but I can't figure it out. I think I need to escape the "ticker" value but I can't seem to figure out how.
This works if I hardcode ticker value to "BTC"
function getCPrice(ticker) {
  var url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest";
  var apiKey = 'replaced-my-api-key'; // Replace with your API key
    var headers = {
    "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY": apiKey,
    "Accept": "application/json"
  };

  var parameters = {
    "symbol": ticker  // **think the issue is here** or works with "BTC"
  };

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "?" + Object.keys(parameters).map(key => key + '=' + parameters[key]).join('&'), {'headers': headers});
var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
var cPrice = json.data[ticker].quote.USD.price;  // works with json.data.BTC.quote.USD.Price

return cPrice;
}

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks in advance,
AT
I was expecting the ticker value passed in to pull the correct crypto price after parsing however I get this error:
Error
Exception: Request failed for https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"status":{"timestamp":"2024-05-16T07:53:46.738Z","error_code":400,"error_message":""symbol" is not allowed to be empty","elapsed":0,"credit_coun... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 56).

How are you using your function getCPrice(ticker)? Can you provide your method for calling the function?

I'm using this through Google sheets, in the Cell I'd like to populate I am trying "=getCPrice(BTC)" -- BTC being the ticker value I'm trying to pass through.

Thank you for replying. About I'm using this through Google sheets, in the Cell I'd like to populate I am trying "=getCPrice(BTC)" -- BTC being the ticker value I'm trying to pass through., in this case, it is required to give the value as a string. So, please put a custom function of =getCPrice("BTC") into a cell.
